# can't clear fields in bootstrap collapsed panels

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, panel

On a search page, I have several bootstrap panels such as this one:

tabSearchPart1

it opens the following tab-pane when click
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_tabSearchPart1"); }

I have a reset button on the top of the page that clears out all the fields:

It calls the following code:

```
    $("#searchReset").click(function () {
        $(':input')
             .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
             .val('')
             .removeAttr('checked')
             .removeAttr('selected');
    });
```

Now, this works perfectly, except in the collapsed tab panels.  If they are collapsed, they won't clear. If I click on the tab to open it and then hit the reset button, it will clear the fields in that tab.

I've tried adding this line inside the block of code above:
$("#tabSearchPart1").collapse('show');
but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried setting each panel to show on hitting reset, before clearing, but all it did was show everything without clearing the fields.

Does anyone know of a way to clear fields in a collapsed panel?

I'd prefer not to involve an event listener because it could end up hitting just when I click on the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is jquery wont act on the non-displaying elements (display:none). I would try overriding the default css for the hidden tab panes.

Default is this:

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tab-content>.active {
   display: block;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    position:absolute;
    top:-99999px;
    left:-99999px;
}

.tab-content>.active {
    position:static;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

(be sure that CSS is added after the default bootstrap CSS)

That will guarantee the elements are available to jQuery, and can then be cleared.

HTH,

-Ted